# Textmate: removing sidebar on the left

Tags: textmate

Is there a way to remove this sidebar from Textmate?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the **View** menu, select **Gutter**, and click to uncheck all of the selected view options there, i.e. **Foldings**, **Bookmarks**, **Line Numbers**, and **Soft Wrap Indicators**. Once all of the above are unchecked, the gutter will disappear.