# How can the gutter in TextMate 2 be disabled?

Tags: text-editor, textmate

Is there a means to disable the gutter in TextMate 2 on OS X? This was apparently [possible](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4127/textmate-removing-sidebar-on-the-left/) in previous versions of TextMate.

[image: Stupid gutters are stupid]

- TextMate version 2.0-beta.8
- OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: you can still choose to show the line numbers or not (view – show/hide line numbers; alt + cmd + L)

Comment: Claus, as it says in the screenshot above, I know the line numbers can be disabled. I'm looking to hide the _entire_ gutter, not just the line numbers. Hiding the line numbers does not hide the gutter.